# Https redirection not working on Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4

I had some issues with my apache configuration and I'm trying to isolate the problem.

I came up with the following lines which are not working :

For testing purposes, I'm trying to redirect all https traffic to Yahoo

The redirection is not working and my web site is showing the index.html file stored in public_html

```
Listen 443  
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443> 
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/example.com/public_html"    
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example
    Redirect permanent / https://www.yahoo.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

The ssl certificate I have was generated by Amazon since my website is hosted on an EC2 instance.

Can anyone help please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, and only the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:443> 
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.yahoo.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache when instructed (as above) sets up name-based filtering. As such, apache
will serve all requests for **example.com** as a **redirect**. The "magic" here is
to keep it simple. So the apache doesn't get confused, and over-think the (your)
intention.